# combine multiple awk commands

Tags: awk

Assuming the following input:

```
$ cat example
{many lines of text}

Col1 Col2  Col3
foo  bar   2 
bar  baz   3
baz  bar   8
bar  foo   0
foo  baz   9
baz  bar   3

{many more lines of text}
```

The following two awk snippets parse out the data I'm after:

```
cat example | awk -v 'RS=\n\n' '/^Col1 /' | awk '$2 == "bar" && $3 > 1 {print $1}'
foo
baz
baz
```

How do I combine the two snippets into a single bit of awk, e.g.

```
awk '
...
...
...
' example
```

Comment: Note that `'RS=\n\n'` only works with gawk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
awk '/^Col1 /,/^$/{ if( $2 == "bar" && $3 > 1 ) print $1}' example
```

Comment: That matches even without the leading blank line, though.

Comment: Good to know, thanks (though not an issue for the use case at hand).

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work.

```
gawk '/^$/{getline;if(/^Col1/){doit=1}else{doit=0;}} doit && $2=="bar" && $3>1 {print $1}' example
```

Broken into readable chunks with comments, this is:

```
/^$/ {                      # Look for a blank line
  getline;                  # Get the next line
  if (/^Col1/) {            # See if your column heads exist.
    doit=1                  # If they do, set a boolean to true
  } else {
    doit=0;                 # Otherwise, false.
  }
}

doit && $2=="bar" && $3>1 { # Check the boolean AND your conditions, then
  print $1                  # print.
}
```

Comment: No problem.  Note that as-is, this will match multiple occurrences of your dataset after a blank line within a file.  If you're confident that only one dataset will be found, or you'd like to grab only the first one, you can add `nextfile;` after the line with `doit=0;`, or if there will only be one input file, simply `exit;`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a flag, set it when found "Col1" as first column and reset it when found a blank line after setting it. Between that, check for the condition of your last pipe:

```
awk '
    $1 == "Col1" { 
        block = 1; 
    } 
    block == 1 && $2 == "bar" && $3 > 1 { 
        print $1; 
    } 
    block == 1 && $0 ~ /^[[:blank:]]*$/ { 
        exit 0; 
    }
' infile
```

Output:

```
foo
baz
baz
```

Comment: Thanks, that's cool and works great! But, is that the only way or is it also possible to parse out some data in the beginning of an awk script and then do something else with that data with another bit of awk? Sort of like piping output from one awk to another, as in the example provided, but inside a single awk script?

Comment: @user145664: Sorry. I don't understand your explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is, is it possible to recreate the flow of the example where dataset that was achieved with the first bit of awk is then piped to the second bit of awk where that dataset is further reduced, but unlike piping from one awk command to another, the whole thing is accomplished inside a single awk script. Basically, maintaining the flow of the example, but without the second invocation of awk?

Comment: William Pursell's example has the flow that I was so poorly trying to explain.